# Best approach to load page to improve performance

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a list of Contacts that shows 5 columns as a grid. On click of each row, slides down  to show Contact details which are another 10 labels. I'm confused between using two approaches:

1. Pull all the Contacts and Contact Details at once and show/hide sections when user clicks.
2. Pull only the Contacts grid once. And on click display the contact details using ajax as user clicks.

Contacts can be anywhere from 100 to 1000.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most performant method based on your scenario as outlined above:

1. Page your grid - don't show 1000 contacts in one go, and write your SQL appropriately.
2. Only show the grid onload.
3. Use AJAX to pull in the contact data and display as required.

---

Might be worth checking though - are the users going to be looking at contact details for everybody they list, or just for single people at a time?  Might affect how you look at the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach would make the whole page load a *bit* slower, though Contact Details would be show immediately at each click. The second one would make page loading faster, though each Contact Detail show would take slightly longer to load (maybe unnoticeable difference if the user has decent internet connection).